# How do I install orbitcpp?

Tags: software-installation

I'm newbie in linux word. I want test CORBA orbitcpp but I didn't find enough information about it. I think I must install orbit2-devel and compile orbitcpp.

So how do I install orbit2-devel and compile the latest version of orbitcpp.

My computer is running Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the latest version from  ftp gnome. look at this [link](ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/orbitcpp/1.3/).

Now download your needed version then build from source.

Comment: Thank you, but now the question is how find and install orbit2-devel ? adding a repository ?

Comment: I found the solution :

Comment: sudo apt-get install liborbit2-dev